# Displaying image in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I'm new in Angular and I try display image ussing assets

I have some service

```
const IMAGES = [
{"id":1, "category": "boats", "caption": "View from the boat", "url":"assets/img/boat_01.jpeg"},
{"id":2, "category": "boats", "caption": "Sailing the coast", "url":"assets/img/boat_02.jpeg"},
{"id":3, "category": "boats", "caption": "The water was nice", "url":"assets/img/boat_03.jpeg"}]

getImages() {
      return this.visibleImages = IMAGES.slice(0);
}
```

In component i use

```
this.visibleImages = this.imageService.getImages();
```

and display it

```
<div class="row">
  <ul id="thumbnailsList">
    <li *ngFor="let imtage of visibleImages" >
      <img src="{{image.url}}" class="tn" width="200" height="160">
      <img src="assets/img/boat_02.jpeg" class="tn" width="200" height="160">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but I have error that cannot display url or undefined but when 
I use

```
<img src="assets/img/boat_02.jpeg" class="tn" width="200" height="160">
```

it's work fine.

Comment: You have a typo in your `*ngFor` directive. It should be `let image of visibleImages` not `imtage`, so that's likely why you're seeing the error.

Answer (score 2):

It's error this is kind of typos

```
<li *ngFor="let imtage of visibleImages" >
```

change to

```
  <li *ngFor="let image of visibleImages" >
```